# Primary constructor call expected

Tags: kotlin

this is example of inheritance in Kotlin.

```
open class Person() {
    var _name : String = ""
    var _age : Int = 0

    constructor(name: String, age : Int)  : this(){
        _name = name
        _age = age
    }
}

class Student() : Person() {
    var _university : String = ""

    constructor (name : String, age: Int, university: String) : super(name, age){
        _university = university
    } 
}

fun main() {
   var person = Person("a", 10)
   var student = Student("b", 18, "MIT")
   println("${person._name} : ${person._age}")
   println("${student._university}")
}
```

How can I resolve error "Primary constructor call expected" in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a class has a primary constructor, you must delegate the secondary constructors to the primary. Which is the case for `Student` class which is not doing so.

First you should remove the boilerplate of `Person` class following Kotlin's idioms (using optional parameters rather than constructor overloading).

```kotlin
// This one's completely optional to do, skip if you don't want to follow idioms
open class Person(
    var name : String = ""
    var age : Int = 0
)
```

And then Student class should have two separate constructors, because if you take a primary constructor then other constructors must delegate to it:

```kotlin
class Student: Person {
    var university: String = ""
    
    constructor() : super()

    constructor (name: String, age: Int, university: String) : super(name, age) {
        this.university = university
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean approach to achieve your desired design concisely will be the following.

For **Parent Class**, defining primary constructor [as part of the class header](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) and using default values for class properties as per your design:

```
open class Person 
constructor (                  
    var _name   : String = "",
    var _age    : Int    = 0
)

// "constructor" keyword can be omitted
```

For **Child Class** similarly defining the primary constructor header definition, omitting the constructor keyword and introducing the third property with it's default value.

Followed by initialising the base class `Person` with the `_name` and `_age` property by calling it's primary constructor.

```
class Student( _name           : String = "",
               _age            : Int    = 0,
               var _university : String = "" ): Person( _name = _name, _age  = _age )
```

Main function:

```
fun main() {
   var person  = Person ("a", 10)
   var student = Student("b", 18, "MIT") // Works.

   // An e.g. for using default value for initialisation (for _name)    
   student     = Student(_age        = 18, 
                         _university = "MIT")      


   println("${person._name} : ${person._age}")
   println("${student._university}")
}
```

---

### BONUS : Secondary Constructor

Incase you need a secondary constructor. Say in the above Student Class example having a secondary constructor to initialise student class from an existing Person object.

Use `this` to initialise the primary constructor from the secondary constructor to avoid the **Primary constructor call expected** error.

```
open class Person (
    var _name   : String = "",
    var _age    : Int = 0
)

class Student(_name           : String  = "",
              _age            : Int     = 0,
              var _university : String  = ""): Person(_name = _name, _age = _age ) 
{
   // secondary constructor
   constructor (person: Person, uni : String) : this( _name       = person._name, 
                                                      _age        = person._age, 
                                                      _university = uni) 
   
}

 

fun main() {
   var person = Person("a", 10)
   var student = Student(person, "MIT")  

   println("${student._name} : ${student._age}")
   println("${student._university}")
}
```